# Arabic and Hebrew text in SVG

Tags: html, svg, adobe-illustrator

I have something set up online where a user can input text into an input field, and that text is then displayed and saved as an SVG file.

It puts the text inside a `<text>` and `<tspan>` node.

The text needs to be certain way, so I attach the `text-anchor` property set to the tspan node with the value of "middle" and I set the `x` property of the tspan node to exactly half the width of the parent.

This works exactly as expected with latin characters, the text is centered and aligned as it should be, both in browser and once the SVG is loaded in Adobe Illustrator.

The issue arises with Hebrew, Arabic and Asian text. They all align as I would expect in Chrome, Safari & Firefox. But in Internet Explorer, and once the the file is loaded into Adobe Illustrator the text seems to be randomly aligned around the file. The font displays correctly, but the positioning is wrong. Playing around with the coordinates and the text-anchor property will shift the text but I cannot get consistent correct results.

The Asian text seems to only shift to the right slightly, the Hebrew and Arabic will align pretty much all over the place.

What am I missing / not understanding?

Edit: Here is some final SVG output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="&#x645;&#x631;&#x62D;&#x628;&#x627;" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0" y="0" width="50px" height="32px" enable-background="new 0 0 50 32" xml:space="preserve">
    <path d="M49.327,24.938c0,6.396-6.604,6.397-6.604,6.397L6.859,31.344c0,0-6.859-0.281-6.859-6.594c0-5.796,0-13.918,0-18.062&#10;&#9;C0-0.187,6.89,0,6.89,0h35.789c0,0,6.648,0.062,6.648,6.562S49.327,18.542,49.327,24.938z"/>
    <path d="M47.171,23.826&#10;&#9;c0,6.259-6.027,5.513-6.027,5.513L8.418,29.346c0,0-6.259,0.904-6.259-5.682c0-4.994,0-11.994,0-15.565&#10;&#9;c0-6.724,6.288-5.763,6.288-5.763h32.659c0,0,6.328-0.522,6.064,5.655C46.933,13.587,47.169,18.315,47.171,23.826z" fill="none" stroke="#000" stoke-width="0.25" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round"/>
    <text>
        <tspan x="25" y="14" fill="#fff" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0.14" stroke-miterlimit="10" font-family="Arial" font-size="8px" text-anchor="middle" letter-spacing="0.035em">&#x645;&#x631;&#x62D;&#x628;&#x627;</tspan>
        <tspan x="25" y="23" fill="#fff" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="0.14" stroke-miterlimit="10" font-family="Arial" font-size="8px" text-anchor="middle" letter-spacing="0.035em">&#x642;&#x637;</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you provide any additional code _(or images?)_ for this problem?

Comment: Added SVG example output.

Comment: Sidenotes from my side: in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47z2M/) _(from the given code example above,)_ it looks like the top line of Arabic text is not getting centered in Chrome... and it looks like the text is being left-aligned in Firefox. As far as the IE and the Adobe issues, those doesn't surprise me too much ;) Which IE and which Illustrator versions are you using when you test this out? _Also, [rtl and text-anchor have differences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor), you may have to adjust for this in the program before outputting the SVG..._

Comment: That is very interesting that it displays that way on JSFiddle, it definitely doesn't show up that when when running on my local machine (or when I open the file directly with a browser).

As far as version of IE & Adobe, I have tried with IE9,10 & 11. And Adobe CS4 and CS6. I can manage without IE support, but I need to figure out what is happening when it is opened in Adobe. InkScape seems to align the text properly though, but I don't think that will be a viable solution.

Comment: As far as text-anchor, I have tried with "start" and "end", neither seem to have the expected results even when adjusting the coordinates.

Comment: Playing around with @summea's fiddle, it looks like what is happening in Chrome, is that it is centering the first letter, not the whole text; in IE, it *is* centering the whole text, both tspans around the initial x value, instead of centering each tspan separately; you could fix that by making them separate `<text>` elements. See http://jsfiddle.net/47z2M/2/ and hover/click the svg to change the text anchor.

Comment: Actually, IE is still buggy even separate from not handling the two `<tspan>` separately: when you align by start or end, it aligns the wrong end of the start/end glyph at the position point.