# Hebrew (and Arabic) text in SVG and Chrome workaround?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js, svg, word-wrap

The Hebrew text in SVG is garbled when using `<tspan>` to split the text into several rows. As one can see in the image the the `y=9` and `dy=1.81em` for the sample text "אאאאאאאאאאא". Despite this fact, the text is displayed on several rows and merged with another part of the text.

[Image of the garbled Hebrew text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFjFd.jpg)

I did a lot of research, and I believe this is a known issue; [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822930/arabic-and-hebrew-text-in-svg) and [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=231628). I can't find any workaround. Is there anybody that can help?

It works perfectly in e.g., firefox so there is nothing wrong with the word-wrap function. I use Chrome version: 55.0.2883.95)

Comment: Oh, [The word-wrapper](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321) that was used for the screenshot.

Comment: As such as it pains me to suggest it, but you cloud sniff out with browser is being used and use a `<foreignObject>` tag for Chrome and `<tspan>` for IE (which doesn't support foreignObject....

Comment: Maybe you could convert the text to paths in Inkscape.

Comment: @RobertLongson Might work, Although this is actually user-generated content so it has to be fixed using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Arabic text and replaced my tspan elements with multiple text elements instead. That worked.